# How to check a string whether contain a substring in Makefile commands

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I want to check whether a string variable contains a specified substring in the Makefile. The purpose is to clean the sub folders.
I used the below code, but it did not work.

```
SERVICES_LIST = A_Service B_Service C_Service #example
SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST = A_Service B_Service
clean:
    @list='$(SERVICES_LIST)';for subdir in $$list;do \
                echo "clean in $$subdir";\
                if [[ "*$$subdir*" == "$(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST)" ]];then\
                make $$subdir clean;\
                fi;\
   done;\
```

Comment: Please format your question using SO's formatting features so it's easier to read.  Also, when asking questions please don't say things like "it did not work"; that doesn't help anyone understand the situation.  Instead, show the command you typed and the output you got (or, if there's a lot of output, at least all the error messages--not just the last lines!!  In fact the FIRST error messages are almost always more important than the last ones, although it's best to include all errors unless there are too many).

Comment: Reverse the order of the equality test, and put the asterisks *outside* the quotes: `if [[ "$(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST)" == *"$$subdir"* ]]`

Comment: Either way around, @Beta, `==` performs a string comparison, not a pattern-match comparison.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: And in this case it works.

Answer (score 0):

This hasn't much to do with `make`, because substantially all the logic involved is expressed in the shell language.  In particular, you seem to be assuming `bash`.

The problem is here:

> ```
>                 if [[ "*$$subdir*" == "$(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST)" ]];then\
> ```

You seem to by trying to match (`make`'s expansion of) `"$(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST)"` against *a glob pattern* formed as (`make`'s expansion of) `"*$$subdir*"`.  But the left-hand side is quoted, so it is not interpreted as a pattern, and the `==` operator performs (exact) string matching, not pattern matching.

One of the main ways to apply such pattern-matching tests in the shell language is with a `case` construct, because the selection expressions used with it are always interpreted as globs.  That might look like so in your makefile:

```
case "$(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST)" in *$$subdir*) make $$subdir clean ;; esac
```

But the whole thing seems pretty non-idiomatic.  Generally speaking, a makefile is tuned to the project.  Even if it is dynamically generated in part or in whole, it is reasonable and appropriate to design your build system so that the clean target can do something more like this:

```
clean:
    for subdir in $(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST); do make -C $$subdir clean; done
```

... or maybe like this:

```
clean: clean_services
    ...

clean_services:
    for subdir in $(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST); do make -C $$subdir clean; done
```

Comment: I change to if [[  "$(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST)" == *"$$subdir"*  ]], but it seems as you said, it's not pattern match, just string comparison. Just to confirm, is there no way to use the if to do pattern string match in the Make command part? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would make it more `make` way by defining a target for cleaning up any supported service and then call all required clean targets as a prerequisite to `clean`. This has additional advantage to make clean in parallel when running with `-j` option as opposed to strictly sequential shell loop.

```
$ cat Makefile
SERVICES_LIST = A_Service B_Service C_Service #example
SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST = A_Service B_Service

.PHONY: $(addsuffix -clean, $(SERVICES_LIST))
$(addsuffix -clean, $(SERVICES_LIST)): %-clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $* clean

.PHONY: clean
clean: $(addsuffix -clean, $(SPECIFIC_SERVICE_LIST))
```